# Relacionamentos condicionais

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relacionamento, active-record, rails4

preciso da vossa ajuda

tenho seguinte modelo:

```
class User < Ac...

   enum user_type: [:normal, :admin]
end
```

E também tenho o modelo "Departamento":

```
class Department < A....

end
```

O que eu preciso é fazer a relação do tipo:

User pertence (belongs_to) a um Departamento, mas apenas quando o tipo for "admin";
E o Departamento deve ter (has_many) vários users mas só do tipo "admin"

Como posso especificar este tipo de relacionamento?

Answer (score 0):

Você vai declarar normalmente, apenas vai tornar opcional.

Quando quiser, pode verificar se a associação existe:

```
u = User.new
u.department.nil?
=> true
u.department_id = Department.first
u.department.nil?
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso do Department é simples:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users , ->(u) { where(user_type:User.user_types[:admin]) }
end
```

No caso do User, o Rails não tem relacionamento condicional. Uma opção seria manter com o belongs_to, e validar na hora da criação/update, para somente deixar criar quando o usuário for do tipo admin.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode detonar o campo `user_type`, e distinguir entre usuários normais e admins pela presença de pelo menos um departamento no cadastro dele? O seu problema parece ser que você está armazenando a informação sobre quem é admin duas vezes:

1. no campo `user_type`
2. no relacionamento com o `Departmento`

*Don’t Repeat Yourself!* Se só admins pertencem a um departamento, use *essa* informação pra distinguir usuários comuns e admins (pra manter compatibilidade com o código que você já escreveu, você pode fazer `user_type` ser uma propriedade computada (não faço a menor ideia de como se faz isso no Ruby; ideal mesmo era ter uma view no banco de dados, pra outros aplicativos também poderem acessar essa propriedade sem precisar reimplementar essa lógica).